# Statistical mode -- how precise should it be?

Tags: statistics, precision

When you're sampling numbers whose precision is much higher than what is practical for your purposes, a naive mode implementation is useless (each sample might very well be unique).
For instance, sampling round-trip time across networked machines. The potential precision of a CPU clock is pretty high. If you only cared about precision down to 1ms or so, and you sampled across a range of pings from Pmax to Pmin, what would be a robust way of measuring the "most common" ping among them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of possible solutions.

(1) construct a histogram, perhaps using automatically-chosen bins. Then report the bin which contains the most data.

(2) fit a parametric distribution to the data and report the mode of that distribution. The simplest example is to fit a Gaussian distribution and report the mean (which equals the mode for a Gaussian distribution). But there are probably other reasonable choices of distributions, which have other parameters to report. E.g. fit a gamma distribution, and report the mode of that.